# Closed form expression for maximizer of $\mathbb{E}[\min\{X, c\}]$?

Tags: expected-value, median, variational-analysis

Let $X$ be a nonnegative random variable such that $\mathbb{E}[X] < \infty$.

I am wondering if it possible to characterize the maximizer, $c > 0$ of the following function:
$$
f(c) = \mathbb{E}\big[\min\{X, c\}\big].
$$

I know  it is equivalent to minimize $-2\min\{X, c\}= 2 \max\{-X, -c\} = - X - c + |X - c|$, hence to minimize
$$
g(c) = \mathbb{E}\big[|X - c|\big] - c.
$$
The first term is minimized at the median of $X$, however, the second term wants $c \to \infty$.

Comment: By monotonicity of expectation, $f$ is increasing.

Comment: Sure, but we also have that $f(c) \leq \mathbb{E}[X]$ for all $c > 0$. Are you saying that $f(c)$ is minimized in the limit $c \to \infty$, with optimal value $\mathbb{E}[X]$, then?

Comment: Seems to be true: $\min\{x, c\} \leq \min\{x, c'\}$, for $c \leq c'$, so applying monotone convergence, we would obtain $\max_{c > 0} f(c) = \lim_{c \to \infty} f(c) = \mathbb{E}[\lim_{c \to \infty} \min\{X, c\}] = \mathbb{E}[X]$.

Comment: Yes that is correct

Answer (score 1):

Based on comments from Mason, we have the monotonicity
$$
\min\{X, c\} \leq \min\{X, c'\}, \quad \mbox{a.s.,}
$$
whenever $c \leq c'$. Consequently, by a monotone convergence argument:
$$
\sup_{c > 0} f(c) = \lim_{c \to \infty} f(c) = \mathbb{E}\Big[\lim_{c \to \infty} \min\{X, c\}\Big] = \mathbb{E}[X]. 
$$